# When use Pedestal, Hoplon, Bidi and Route-one?

Tags: clojure, routes, pedestal, hoplon

**I** am trying figure out which one (Pedestal, Hoplon, Bidi) should i use? I didn't find any good article in the Internet which help me with this choice.

From https://github.com/juxt/bidi i can read Pedestal is isomorphic, but Bidi is also cljs. What is it mean? What is the difference?

**I** found compojure is too simply. I can't even generate URLs in HTML templates. I started looking something else. I found also route-one (library to generate URLs working with compojure), but i guess soon i will discover i need something more then compojure have again.

My intuition say me to choose between: Pedestal, Hoplon and Bidi.

**W**hat i need:
I want have independent business model architecture like

http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

http://blog.find-method.de/index.php?/archives/209-Dependency-inversion-in-Clojure.html

I don't want depend this part of code with any framework. Less dependency is better.

**O**n next stage i want inject this model business into something like bridge, which will be the connector with user interface. It can be time for framework or additional libraries.

And at least i want create frontend user interface as website. It will be dynamic content with ClojureScript or mayby static. I don't know. I have to thing about both.

**W**hat i found out in Clojure i really like conception of building my own set of libraries based on my preferences. But i don't want write my own code to use things like generate URLs for routes. So mayby i should also consider route-one?

**P**lease write something clever what help me choose one or complicate my live with some other option to choose :)

https://github.com/juxt/bidi

https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal

https://github.com/tailrecursion/hoplon

https://github.com/clojurewerkz/route-one

Comment: Hi Kabra, this question is probably a bit too broad. Can you narrow down what you're asking, and be more clear about your own requirements?

Comment: It can be hard, because i don't know what i don't know :)

What i learned from yesterday: bidi and route-one is routing library. Route-one is very simple, bidi work also in frontend with ClojureScript.

Pedestal and Hoplon are more complex tools. Pedestal is focus more on backend side like RESTful applications. Hoplon is focus more on frontend side. Still both do the same.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is an ancient question, and I don't pretend to have an answer (much less "the" answer). But I'm googling for some of the same basic pieces tonight, and my search results came back with this response.

So I figured I'd jot down notes about my [very] limited understanding here.

Bidi seems awesome. From what I've seen, juxt produces very high quality software. For places where I need REST-style interface routing (which includes sending related routes back), this is my current GOTO choice.

Pedestal - also awesome. But it seems to be a very different use case. Routing
is a very small subset here (and they've tried multiple approaches to come up with a really good set of options). This seems to be more of a fairly low-level full-featured server-side library for integrating the code you care about with the underlying server pieces that you don't.

To be honest, I'm not sure Pedestal's routing libraries really support the reverse endpoints you have to have for REST. I think they almost definitely do, but I'm not positive. My use cases have all been about their interceptor chaining abstraction, which is mind-blowingly awesome.

Hoplon - I haven't looked at this in 2-3 years. At the time, it seemed like a big, bold, high-level kitchen-sink framework that's somewhere in the same ballpark as Ruby On Rails (although I think there are also front-end components). I've been writing API end-points, and this didn't seem like a good fit at the time. It deserves more attention than I gave it.

route-one - I hadn't heard about it before this question. I've gotten good impressions from everything that I have used from clojurewerkz, but that usage has been very light.